# How do I get a pointer to a vector item, that I only have a reference to?

Tags: c++

This is my first time trying to use a Vector so I'm still learning.  I passed in a reference to the vector for one of my methods:

```
int Packetizer::depacketize(vector<Packet> *packets, uint8_t *imgBuffer){
```

Now I want to try two things, one get a reference to the last packet to get some info I know is in there. Then two iterate over the vector without popping the values off.  I figured I could do that with a packet pointer.

```
Packet* _packet;
_packet = packets->back();
```

and later

```
_packet = packets->at(seq);
```

When I compile it says:

> error: cannot convert
>   ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits,
>   Packet>::value_type’ {aka ‘Packet’} to ‘Packet*’ in assignment
>   _packet = packets->back();

Am I misunderstanding the return of back()? I thought docs said it would give me a reference to the last element. Should I be casting that into a packet or something like that?

Thank you.

Comment: a reference is an alias. In a nutshell, what you do with the reference you could as well do with the actual object and vice versa, `&x` gets you the address  of `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the term "reference" is midleading. You're dealing with pointers, not references.

`packets->back()` returns a `Packet&` (reference to a Packet) not a `Packet*` (pointer to a packet).

```
Packet& _packet = packets.back()
```

Is closer to what you need. _packet is a reference to the back of the collection. i.e. it's an alias, not a copy. Quite similar to a pointer `Packet*`, but it's like an alias object instead of pointer that points to the target.

Comment: Thank you I was thinking back returned a Packet*.  So I guess this  Packet _packet = packets->back(); would get be a copy of the packet object at the end of the vector, and Packet& get's me a "reference" to that packet value.  Kind of like getting the address of it.

Comment: This is inaccurate: "returns a `Packet`" should be "returns a `Packet&`". Also, packets is a pointer, not a reference, so should use arrow operator in your example. (Too small of an edit, SO won't allow me to change just that.)

Comment: I ended up doing this Packet * _packet= &(packets->back()); after watching and understanding what was returned in gdb.  Thanks for the help!